# error 'TempSLLNODE' : use of class template requires template argument list

Tags: c++, templates

```
#ifndef TEMPLATE_LINKED_LIST
#define TEMPLATE_LINKED_LIST


template <class T>
class TempSLLNODE
{
public:
    T info;
    TempSLLNODE *next;
    TempSLLNODE( T value, TempSLLNODE *ptr = NULL)
    {
        info = value;
        next = ptr;
    }
};

template <class T>
class TempSLL
{
public:
    TempSLL()
    {
        head = tail = 0;
    }
    ~TempSLL();
    T isEmpty()
    {
        return head == 0;
    }
    void addToHead(T);
    void addToTail(T);
    T deleteFromHead();   // delete the head and return its info;
    T deleteFromTail();   // delete the tail and return its info;
    void deleteNode(T);
    bool isInList(T) const;
private:
    TempSLLNODE *head, *tail;
};

#endif
```

Comment: You are not going to comment on your code **at all** ??

Comment: as @Nabla said, you should explain your problem with real words, because we are human after all. If you don't we'll not be able to help you and you post will be deleted...

Answer (score 1):

`TempSLLNODE` is template, you need to use it with type:

update:

```
TempSLLNODE *head, *tail;
```

to:

```
TempSLLNODE<T> *head, *tail;
//         ^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

You could at least mention the line of the error.
For future reference, the error is here:

```
private:
    TempSLLNODE *head, *tail;
```

You need to know that when you instantiate a variable from a class template, you should mention the template type. In fact, for each template type you use to instantiate a variable, the compiler compiles and generates code of the class for you, and before doing so, compiler does not generate any code for the class template.

So I guess what you meant here is:

```
private:
    TempSLLNODE<T> *head, *tail;
```

Comment: C++ does not have generics. It has class templates.

Comment: You're calling it a "template class" now. It is a _class template_, as I said.